# Why does Python produce a MemoryError when I open this file

Tags: python, memory, io

I am trying to remove empty lines from a file. My method is reading the file line by line and writing any lines which are not just newlines to a new file. it works great for small files, but for reasons I don't understand, I'm getting a MemoryError on larger ones. The problem file is over 1GB, but since I'm reading it line by line, I don't think I'm storing more than one line in memory. Or am I?

```
with open(output_path, "ab+") as out_file:
    with open(input_path, "rb") as in_file:
        line = in_file.readline()
        while line:
            if line != "\n":
                out_file.write(line)
            line = in_file.readline()
```

When I split the file into chunks, it works fine, but that's a step I'd rather not do. I want to understand what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: How many lines are in the file and how big is it? Count them with `wc -l filename ` and `du filename`.

Comment: Are you sure the file has line breaks? If it doesn't, one "line" is the whole file.

Comment: @Blender The file has 62,857 lines. It's tab-separated data I pulled down from a SQL table using bcp.

Comment: Opening a file in binary mode and then using `readline` seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was elsewhere in the code. I wasn't explicitly closing a file, which led to this issue. Thanks all for your help.